# Correct peoples grammar

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language

(yes, that title was intentional)

Your task is to correct common grammatical mistakes.

You must:

- Capitalise the first letter of each sentence, ie the first non-whitespace letter after any of `.!?` and, additionally, capitalise the first letter of the input
- Remove repeating punctuation, such as `!!! -> !`. Ellipses (`...`) are not special, and will collapse into `.`.
- Remove repeating whitespace `<space><space><space> -> <space>`
- Remove whitespace directly before any of `.,;!?` as in: `Hello , World ! -> Hello, World!`
- If there is no space directly after any of `.,;!?`, add it.
- Add a `.` at the end of the input if there is not any of `.!?` at the end.
- <s>Not use Mathematica's builtins</s>

### Examples:

```
This is a  sentence .Unfortunately, it's not very grammatically correct.can you fix it ???
This is a sentence. Unfortunately, it's not very grammatically correct. Can you fix it?

buffalo, buffalo;buffalo   buffalo? Buffalo.buffalo Buffalo buffalo
Buffalo, buffalo; buffalo buffalo? Buffalo. Buffalo Buffalo buffalo.

i'm not sure what to put for this test case...
I'm not sure what to put for this test case.

!this is a test. .Can ...you . . . 'ear me Ground-Control? ?! 'ere as in what you do with you're [sic] ears !
! This is a test. Can. You. 'ear me Ground-Control?! 'ere as in what you do with you're [sic] ears!
```

Comment: `"what about this?"`, `"(or this.)"`? (I'm guessing `"what about this? ".` and `(or this. ).`, which is a shame, but golf be golf...)

Comment: What are all the possible characters that can appear in the input?

Comment: Your last test case seems wrong, since nothing in the post says we need to remove repeated punctuation with whitespace inbetween.

Comment: would rules number 5 and 6 clash and end up having a trailing output of <space>.<space>.<space>.<space>.<space>.

Comment: I like this challenge but I guess a better title might be "Correct peoples grammar according to the given rules". The rules are specific enough about what is required for me. If I am not misunderstanding, as long as the test cases are matched then the answer is valid. If my comment is grammatically incorrect then please feel free to use it as a further test case.

Comment: Do leading whitespace have to be removed?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Not unless there is any of `.,;!?` after the whitespace at the start.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>80</s> <s>74</s> <s>73</s> <s>71</s> <s>74</s> <s>64</s> <s>65</s> <s>62</s> <s>78</s> 72 bytes

```
 *([.,;!? ])(\1| )*
$1
T`l`L`[.!?].|^.
([.,;!?])(\w|')
$1 $2
[^.!?]$
$&.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#PU9BTsMwELz7FRMpkLYKlsq1B0v0UA4ciziEVjGuQy05NrI3lEj9e7FLirzSjj2zntm72aa9YDFreL0qBHbz2fvyjPmClUu2bW370ja8EDt@3nM2ibLmdK7mSYLykTX7LChZec8vl2dtrUeNNx/sAQXbHk1EKglE7Ug7pcFfXecDDU6StmMNQ1WE84RvHUZ8Btn3koyS1o5QPgStiCvpMPoBnflJeggh2MfQddL6GhNYTR24vYgb4DfqaerTnZmqvzrHIWicjpJAHl8DIQUE5eykI0HJqDnnrPOeFfS/UuY4@DplS2yOx6@n0jKg19gEP7jDw9o7Ct4KiCJRyUimefdnl4cOHidDx4yrxDbRqB3SFxHFLw)

This is my first Retina answer.

-12 bytes thanks to [@BusinessCat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53880/business-cat)!

-3 bytes thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil).

Comment: I _think_ you can replace `\s` with a literal space. OP said there won't ever be newlines and I'm assuming there won't be tabs either.

Comment: There should be a space after punctuation like `;`

Comment: Also `([^.!?])(?m:$)` `$1.` -> `[^.!?]$` `$&.`.

Comment: @KritixiLithos Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @BusinessCat Thanks, but `$` still seems to need a multiline modifier.

Comment: Ah. When you run all test cases at once it will. If you do one at a time it would be fine. You could also precede the line with `%\`` (which executes the stage on each line separately) instead of using the modifier.

Comment: You don't need to count code added solely to run multiple test cases at once. On TIO, normal practice is to put ``%(G` `` in the Header area instead.

Comment: @Neil Did just that, thanks.